# How to restrict access to a media-File in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-file-upload

I've an application where my users create a video-file (mp4) which is saved as a Filefield in the model.

In my view I add the object (model) to the context of a TemplateView class.

In my HTML I use the video tag and use the "src" to add the url and to display the video. I restrict the view to the owner only.

This all works fine.

But now anyone can see the videos if they get the url (used in "src"). How can I restrict access the the files ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting access to private file downloads in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166784/restricting-access-to-private-file-downloads-in-django)

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi, it does ... I changed my nginx settings to use XSendfile. But this gives another issue. Then my videos cannot play on iOS anymore .... ? [Nginx XSendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73154226/edit) your question and include that information as it may help someone identify your issue more quickly.

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi, it doesn't work ... seems that all solutions are about downloading a file. I do want to play a video.